# How to insert ascii characters into text - Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, ascii

Linux newbie here. On Windoze I sometimes **insert individual ascii characters into a text** using left Alt + a 3-digit code on the numeric keypad. Haven't found anything like that for Ubuntu. Is there?

I have keyboards for other languages installed, but rarely compose in one of them. Just need that occasional ß or ü etc.

Xubuntu 22.04 on Dell Latitude e6530

Comment: On my keyboard (not english or german) I have a `Alt GR` button on the right side of space. Pressing `Alt GR+S` becomes `ß`. For double dots over letters, the key to the right of `P` when pressed with `Alt GR` allow me to add `¨` over almost any letter, including `ü`. This is not exclusive to Linux, it works on Windows too.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably typing Ctrl-Shift-U and then the hex value of the Unicode codepoint, followed by enter. For example, Ctrl-Shift-U followed by df <enter> gives you a sharp s, ß.

Comment: Thanks, didn't work for me on Xubuntu 22.04, Dell Latitude e6530, 16 Gb RAM. I've got a German keyboard I can switch to, no problem. I'd like to be able to "print" fractions, like 1/2, 1/4, 3/4, as I can under Windoze